# How do I prevent an ActiveRecord child object being saved when the parent is invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation (parsing) where I need to begin with child records, add their logical parent, and then save while validating both the child and the parent.

Is there a standard way to handle this with Rails?

Given the following relationships:

- Parent `has_many` Child, `validates :child, presence: true`
- Child `belongs_to` Parent

I'm seeing something like the following:

```
p = Parent.new # with a missing required attribute
c = Child.new
c.parent = p # or c.parents << p, this isn't important
p.valid? # false
c.valid? # true
c.save # true
```

So it's letting me save the child while the newly-associated parent object has errors.

Is there a conventional way to solve this? I believe this works properly when the objects are swapped, as expected given their relationship.

However, I can't begin with the parent in this case because it may exist already, and I do a separate `find_or_create` for this. It's more logical to begin with the child records in this case.

Google/SO searches didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `custom validator` in your child model like the following:

```
  validate parent_model_validate
```

And, then add the `parent_model_validate` method in the same (child) model:

```
  def parent_model_validate
    unless self.parent.valid?
      errors.add(:child_model, 'Parent is not valid')
    end
  end
```

This validator will make sure that, if the parent model is not valid, then the child model will not be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `validates_associated` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated).
(Please note to not use it on both ends)